# Error while passing the variable for a graphql query in Spring boot client

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graphql, console.log

I am working on a project and trying to use the GraphQL backend server in my SpringBoot application. I have written a client which connects to graphQL backend and creates/fetches the data but when I am trying to pass the variable from the application and pass with a query then it's throwing an error.
But it's working fine if I just comment the variable part and hardcode the value directly in query.

**Mutation Query**-
mutation($names: String!) {
createList (name: $names){
updated
listId
name
}
}

**Variable** -
{
"names" : "bagName"
}

**Java Client** -

'''

```
public CreateListDto getFavouritesDetails(String shoppingListName, String customerId, String storeId, String langId) throws IOException {

        GraphqlRequestBody graphQLRequestBody = new GraphqlRequestBody();

        System.out.println("print this"+shoppingListName+"custId"+customerId);
        final String query = GraphqlSchemaReaderUtil.getSchemaFromFileName("createList");
        String variables = GraphqlSchemaReaderUtil.getSchemaFromFileName("variables");
        graphQLRequestBody.setVariables(variables.replace("bagName", "Avisss"));
        graphQLRequestBody.setQuery(query);
        //System.out.println("graphQLRequestBody----------"+graphQLRequestBody.getQuery());
        System.out.println(graphQLRequestBody.getVariables());
        CreateListDto webClient = WebClient.builder().defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
            httpHeaders.set("X-User-Id", "XXXXXXXXXXX");
            httpHeaders.set("X-Retail-Id",storeId );
            httpHeaders.set("X-Is-Anonymous", Boolean.toString(true));
        }).build()
                .post()
                .uri(url)
                .bodyValue(graphQLRequestBody)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(CreateListDto.class)
                .blockFirst();
        System.out.println(graphQLRequestBody.getQuery());
        //System.out.println(graphQLRequestBody.getVariables());

        return webClient;
```

'''

**Maven dependencies** --

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Getting below error in console together with printing the request System outs** -

*GraphQL Request Body ::: - mutation{
createList(name: "sl114") {
updated
listId
name
}
}
GraphQL Request variable ::: - {
"name" : "Avisss"
}*

> 

2022-01-23 16:29:40.697 ERROR 3748 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/shoppingbag] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST https://dev.test.com/graphql] with root cause

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST https://dev.test.com/graphql
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:196) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ 400 from POST https://dev.test.com/graphql [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:196) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:207) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.13.jar:3.4.13]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.13.jar:3.4.13]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101) ~[reactor-core-3.4.13.jar:3.4.13]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved. There were two issues - 1) with the graphQL schema ad 2) with the WebClient.

I corrected the schema and using the HttpClient instead of WebClient.